# delay after clicking blackberry application icon

Tags: blackberry, wait

i can't seem to figure out the following situation:

when i i click on my blackberry app icon (within the simulator), the application pops up quick, no problems. however, when i take that same code and push it to my blackberry, there is a few seconds of wait time after the icon has been clicked.

can someone tell me how to minimize the delay? the first screen is NOTHING but an image inside a image field. i wanted to create a "splash" screen and i just show you a simple image.

after i click on the app icon (on my phone), i notice that there is activity because you see the arrows in the upper right-hand corner moving. but to the regular non-techie user, they won't know that the application has been started and they will just keep clicking the icon over and over again.

again, i click on the app icon and there is about a 3 second delay just to the image contained within the project folder. so we are not fetching the image from a remote site.

the simulator shows the image fast, but the phone creates a delay. any ideas how to minimize the delay after app icon click?

thank you.

ac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. i just moved the instantiating and loading of several objects to a different class and later called those lines of code with an invokeLater method. my first screen only contains the image itself and the other class contains the rest of the code.